# Wrap every 3 elements from multi dimensional array in a div with specific class

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of products :

```
$products = array(
0 => array(
"name" => "product1",
),
1 => array(
"name" => "product2",
),
2 => array(
"name" => "product3",
),
3 => array(
"name" => "product4",
),
4 => array(
"name" => "product5",
),
5 => array(
"name" => "product6",
 ),
);
```

On every row I can have 3 products. I need to wrap those products in a div with class gray_div and the others 3 products in a div with class blue_div.

```
<div class="gray_div">
 product1   product 2 product 3
</div>

<div class="blue_div">
 product4   product 5 product 6
</div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: Only a simple foreach, I managed to display all but I don't know how to separate by divs at every 3 elements counted from array.

Comment: @Y.Hermes Have you got something against `$product[1]["name"]`

Comment: @Y.Hermes I have more than 6 products..I need to be automatic.

Comment: Without further informations it's hard to know what he really want to achieve

Comment: @Y.Hermes I have more products than 6, every 3 products from array are wrapped in a div with class gray_div, after that the next 3 products from array in a div with class blue_div and so on. I want to know how to make a loop based on this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) in PHP

```
$newArray = array_chunk($products, 3);
foreach ($newArray as $key => $product) {
    echo '<div class="'.(($key % 2) ? "blue_div" : "gray_div").'">';
    foreach ($product as $p) {
        echo $p['name']." ";
    }
    echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But this only adds div with class gray_div, how can I alternate divs classes at every 3 products ? div with class gray_div, after count of 3 products, the next 3 products wrapped in a div with class blue_div ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_chunk` and `array_walk_recursive` to flatten the chunks and do it all in one go.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($products,3);

foreach($chunks as $key=>$chunk){

    $products = [];

    array_walk_recursive($chunk, function($value) use (&$products) {
        $products[] = $value; 
    });


    if ($key%2==0){
        $color = 'gray';
    }
    else{
        $color = 'blue';
    }

    print '<div class="' . $color . '_div">' . implode(' ',$products) . '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will output

```
<div class="gray_div">product1 product2 product3</div>
<div class="blue_div">product4 product5 product6</div>
```